# Is there a way to select a dropdown using its display name where the dropdown is populated from the database not from a HTML?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I was wondering if there was a way to select a selection from the dropdown menu where all the selection is populated from the database and does not have any selectors.

As it does not have any selectors we cannot use `await page.select("selector",'dropdown')`
 I have also tried using

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector(`select [value="District"]`).selected = true);
});
```

Right now just to make it work I am using

```
    Page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
    page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
    page.keyboard.press('Enter')
```

which selects the selection I want but I don't think this is an appropriate way to select a selection from a dropdown.

There must be a proper way, Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by `all the selection is populated from the database and does not have any selectors.` it doesn't make sense  ... maybe a picture can be helpful

Comment: @hretic I mean that after the dropdown is clicked a query runs which populates the all the dropdown values not that the values are populated from the frontend!